# Angular PWA Offline data handling

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

in recent days I've started hearing about service workers which are cool. I want to implement the service workers in my angular project to make my web app completely works offline which means the user should handle the data as much in offline and once they found internet then the data should get updated with the MongoDB (Which we are using for the database). I'm hearing about indexeddb but I don't know how to integrate it with my angular. Any proper angular way of doing this. Or any good tutorial to follow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Angular using with IndexedDB use local forage offline data management API created by Mozzila team. please refer this link: https://localforage.github.io/localForage/    if you have using angular 2+ then refer to this link: https://github.com/Alorel/ngforage/ .  it is working fine in my projects happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use background sync feature to enable offline mode for your data puch to server side and sync when user is online .

[Check on this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) on how to implement it.